# quantal: suddenly, notify-osd doesn't show bubbles

Tags: notify-osd, notify-send

using quantal and don't see notify bubbles anymore on my desktop. Using the command notify-send, I see that if i do in the terminal `notify-send -u critical Test Test`, i see the bubble showing up. But if i do: `notify-send -u normal Test Test` or just `notify-send Test Test` i see no bubbles!

Maybe **Do not disturb** mode has been applied probably, but I don't know how/when!

```
$ notify-send --version 
notify-send 0.7.5

$ apt-cache policy notify-osd
notify-osd:
    Installed: 0.9.34-0ubuntu5
    Candidate: 0.9.34-0ubuntu5
Version table:
*** 0.9.34-0ubuntu5 0
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the incriminated packages with:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install libnotify-bin notify-osd`

Comment: Hello :), reinstalled both, and notify-send Test Test and no bubble! notify-send -u critical test test, bubble shows up!